# Lambda expression in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I program in C# and I need to do lambda expression in Visual Basic same as:

```
var password = Database.Users.Where(x => x.username == username).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This is vb.net, please remove the VBA tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x =>` is replaced with `Function(x)` in VB.NET

The full line becomes

`Dim password = Database.Users.Where(Function(x) x.username = username).FirstOrDefault()`

But can also be written like:

`Dim password = Database.Users.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.username = username)`